# Joined Head won't move with the rest of rig

Tags: rigging, parent

I joined a head after I made a body for my character. and once I tried to move the head to make a pose the head refuses to move.

[image: enter https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vv3fF.jpg]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fuAKo.jpg]

Comment: did you create the head after you parented the body to the armature? did you parent the head to the head bone?

Comment: first question Yes, and second question No.

Comment: Select your object and go in Edit mode, then go to the Vertex Groups menu in the menu Properties > Object Data, you'll see all the Vertex Groups of your mesh, they have been given the name of the bone they have been assigned to when you've parented with Automatic Weight. Is there a Vertex Group called by the name of your head bone? if yes, then select the Vertex Group, select the head vertices and click assign. If not, then click on the "+" button and create a new Vertex Group called by the name of the bone, then select the head vertices and click assign. It should work.

Comment: you can also switch your armature to Pose mode, the switch your object to Weight Paint mode, then select the bone you want to assign vertices to, then paint with the brush with the Add or Substract option enabled. Add will increase the influence of the bone on the part of mesh you paint, Substract will decrease it, red color will mean 100% influence, blue color will mean 0%.

Comment: Thanks, moonboots, but I'm having a hard time finding what you're talking about. Could you maybe upload an image showing where the object data menu is, please? It would be a super huge help, thanks again.

Comment: https://zupimages.net/up/18/25/bdx8.jpg